# Trying to do a password reset in Laravel 5.5, Is there a way of doing an update in password_reset table rather than a deletion command

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is the error I encounter when I pass my email during password reset. Instead of doing a delete can I do an Update? If Yes where in the files can I be able to make the changes?

I have tried to do a delete query of the email passed in the ForgotPasswordCOntroller.php index function(I wrote one) file before it is passed to the SendsPasswordResetEmails.php file but the error persists.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 DELETE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'password_resets' (SQL: delete from `password_resets` where `email` = my@email.com)

Is there a work around to this?

My User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes, HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'tbl_users';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'user_type',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Comment: SoftDeletes exactly solves this problem

Comment: that's a permission issue of db user on that table

Comment: @Sakezzz where exactly do I add the soft delete? In the users model?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo is there a way around it? Like instead of deleting we do an update?

Comment: @Geto yes, also you should add migration

Comment: @Sakezzz lemme try

Comment: @Sakezzz it hasn't worked

Comment: what it writes and what did you do?

Comment: The error is the same, I just added the softdelete to the users model and did the same to the migration respectively

Comment: can you write user model in post?

Comment: I have @Sakezzz

Comment: @Geto thats ok. How you delete?